# Close woocomerce frontend and only keep the backend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, frontend

What I'm trying to do:

- Only vendors can submit their products.
- They can't see other vendors
  products.

I will open the front end of the website when there is enough products submitted.

**My question is;** Is there any way that I can close the front end of woocomerce website and only keep the back end?

Or any other idea to solve this?

Comment: You can unpublish, cart, shop and checkout pages til you are ready.

Comment: Good idea, But what about the products on the main page? but still there is a search option! on all pages, it will show the product

Comment: The direct link won't be available anywhere right? - You can make the product visibility hidden, so it won't come in search as well